# C# - What is the Select Source dialog as it applies to the GetDevice method?

Tags: c#, select, device, twain

I am trying to use a method that is described like this:

> ```
> public Device GetDevice(string productName)
> ```
>
> The `productName` is the name of the device as it appears in the Select Source dialog.

What is the *Select Source dialog* that's being referred to?

Comment: Please give us more information about your problem. In which framework is that method?

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't mean to have you scratching your heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this link](http://www.atalasoft.com/docs/dotimage/docs/Getting_Started_with_DotISIS.html) mentions (look for the "*Showing the “Select Source” dialog*" heading), this is a dialog that allows users to select an ISIS device. It's [part](https://www.atalasoft.com/docs/dotimage/docs/Atalasoft.DotTwain~Atalasoft.Twain.Acquisition~ShowSelectSource.html) of the DotImage framework, called with `ShowSelectSource` and is used like this:

```
IsisDevice dev = null;
if (this.acquisition.ShowSelectSource(this)) dev = this.acquisition.Devices.Default;
```

I would guess that this works similarly to a `FolderBrowserDialog`. The user selects the device of his choosing and you can then use his selection to retrieve the Device itself with `GetDevice`.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for not being specific enough. I just got thrown on this project with no direction. First time working with actual hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Google to find out which library you are using.

Anyway: open the atalasoft [documentation](https://www.atalasoft.com/docs/dotimage/docs/), once there, click search, and search for 'select AND source AND dialog'. Click the secondd hit '2:   Getting Started with DotTwain' and read 'Showing the "Select Source" dialog'